# How to flush ElastiCache Memcached cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have 2 AWS ElasticCache - Memcached nodes. 
How can I **flush all** the data in those nodes? 
Is there a aws-cli command I can use? Is there any other way we can do it through AWS Console?

Answer (score 3):

One thing which worked for me atlast:

*telnet xxxx.yyyy.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com 11211*

**flush_all**

I'm still open to find other ways to do this.

Answer (score -1):

We use php client for memcache and trigger flush_all whenever needed

Comment: This isn't a PHP question.